# Android Studio 1.2.1.1 on Windows 10 giving Permission denied error

Tags: android, windows-10, permission-denied

I have been running Android Studio 1.2.1.1 on my Windows 7 PC just fine.  However, after upgrade to Windows 10,  I get following error when running an app.  And as a result the emulator is not launching.

> NAND: could not read file
>   c:\Users\abcuser\AppData\Local\Android\sdk/system-images\android-22\default\x86/system.img,
>   Permission denied

When I checked the path under the abcuser folder, none of folders from above error exist under the path.  Appdata folder and its child folders simply do not exist.

I am completely stuck here. Please advise how can we get pass above error.

Comment: Try running android studio as admin

Answer (score 3):

I got Same error before some time this is because in above path some folder have not `read only permission`.

And if you do not find Appdata folder it is because of this are hide folder so before do this unhide all item for this "Users" folder.

And check all folder with right click on it, then go to Properties and Checked "Read-Only".[image]

It worked in my case hope will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Windows:

Go by the given path (c:\Users\(your username)\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\system-images\android-22\default\x86\system.img - which can be different for various users) until you reach system.img file.

Then, go to the file properties (right click) -> security tab, and
just make sure to give "Full permissions" to the relevant user.